# A low-code automation to upload folders of documents to individual envelopes in DocuSign?

Tags: automation, docusignapi

I have multiple folders that contain multiple documents each. Each folder's documents need to be uploaded into individual envelopes in DocuSign. Is there a low-code way to accomplish this? I've tried Power Automate with a custom connector, but am only able to do a single document at a time. I need to apply the same template, that has all the anchor tag info, to each document.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, no. It would be possible to write a script in something like Bash or PowerShell to create a base set of envelope definitions, then iterate through the folders documents creating an envelope for each one.

If the documents weren't unique you could use something like bulk send, however if they're going to be on a per document basis that's not going to cut it. Unfortunately this isn't something we have examples on how to do, however I can tell you that yes it is absolutely possible.

Regards,

Matt

Comment: All of the documents will be unique, and all of the signers will be unique. They will all have the same template, which outlines the anchor tags applied.  Do you have any resources you can point me in the direction of? Thank you!!!

Comment: Not exactly. We have examples on how to pull in specific files and add them as part of an envelope that you could use as a roadmap, we call these 'composite templates.' Basically they give you the ability to merge server-side and local envelope definitions. In this case you would iterate through a folder, then have it send an envelope referencing the new doc at the base-level of the definitions and the server-side template in the top-level. This pulls in the template elements and replaces the underlying document but leaves the anchor tabs. Have you opened a support case? This gets tricky.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I will look more into composite templates. I have not opened a support case. Thank you for you patience with my lack of knowledge, but where would I even open a support case?

Comment: You can open a case at support.docusign.com -- it should be routed to myself or someone from my team and we can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could build this in [Linx](https://linx.software). It is a general-purpose low-code platform for building backends like APIs, automations and integrations. It is based on an abstraction of programming itself and not domain, process or tooling specific. This means it can be used to build your application using programming concepts.